# Codeigniter set_output function not working with image

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get the image as output, but it seems like `set_output()` function is not working properly with content type `jpeg` 
My Code is given below...

```
$image = file_get_contents('assets/images/ThinkstockPhotos-145054512_small.jpg');
$this->output->set_content_type('jpeg')->set_output($image);
```

When I replace the image with a plain text file, in that case, it shows me the correct output

```
$file = file_get_contents('assets/images/test.txt'); 
$this->output->set_content_type('text')->set_output($file);
```

I have change content type from `set_content_type('jpeg')` to `set_content_type('jpg')` and `set_content_type('gif')` but stil it does not work and not show me on output.

What output I am getting now is shown in screenshot given below.

[image]

Comment: Try `image/jpeg` instead of just `jpeg`

Comment: Done it, but still not working and results are same as preivous

Comment: Pls cross check and make sure that your jpeg mime-type settings in config/mimes.php

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue on my localhost setup only when I provided `file_get_contents` either a (1) bad path or (2) a non-existent image. I think you need to provide a full path to the image as with any directory/file related operation.

Try using `FCPATH` that is where you `index.php` lies and I assume your `assets/` folder as well.

```
public function index() {
    $file = FCPATH . 'assets/images/ThinkstockPhotos-145054512_small.jpg';

    if (!is_file($file)) {
        exit('File not found!');
    }

    $image = file_get_contents($file);
    $this->output->set_content_type('jpeg')->set_output($image);
}
```

Note: if you get `File not found!` then assure that the file exists in `/htdocs/assets/...` where `/htdocs/index.php` is your main CI file

Comment: I have applied if condition, with 'FCPATH' and without 'FCPATH'. But in both cases, if condition says "File exists".

Comment: You mean doesn't exist ;) where is your file exactly. Starting from your document root.

Comment: if (!is_file($file)) echo 'File not found!'; else echo 'File exist';
As per this condition, it says File Exist

Comment: ah you put an else. yea i mean i dont get it, if the file exists and the path is ok file get contents should work

Comment: Please check if the condition carefully, There is an Exclamation mark on if condition. Means if file not exist then echo 'File not found', if file found then echo 'File exist '

Comment: yea i know... but you are saying the else condition is working and saying file exists... i'm saying thats weird if you arent getting any output when I do with a valid file, and that white dot without.  have you tried another image?

Comment: Yes, i've tried with different images. but results are same. But when i tried with plan text(.txt) file. It shows me the correct content of file.
Only issue is with image file.